# fatal exception timer-0 when collecting GPS data at particular interval in Android

Tags: android

I have used the below link to get Latitude & Longitude. If GPS or Network are not able to get the value means I got fatal exception in Timer-0

[What is the simplest and most robust way to get the user's current location on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145089/what-is-the-simplest-and-most-robust-way-to-get-the-users-current-location-in-a?lq=1)

How to handle when data unavailabilty?